# Error reading Prometheus: Post "https://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp [::1]:9090: connect: connection refused

Tags: metrics, prometheus, telemetry

I am working on connecting grafana to prometheus server for visualising node metrics
I have been following the substrate docs https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/node-metrics/#configure-prometheus-to-

I followed each step in docs as is but I am facing issue while connecting the Grafana to prometheus
the error is "Error reading Prometheus: Post "https://localhost:9090/api/v1/query": dial tcp [::1]:9090: connect: connection refused"

I tried searching this issue but could not get anything relevant ,  has anyone done this before or can help me in understand If I am doing anything wrong or missing anything.  As I am following the above docs ,  I run the substrate node first, than prometheus server and than try to connect Grafana https://localhost:9090/
I tried grafana local and cloud both for this[image]

Comment: Hi, try using `http://localhost:9090` (without the `s`).

Comment: I have done that too, it result in the same error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1040 fixes this

Comment: strangely the header shows as "off topic" - it's not! Thanks for identifying the issue :) 
When you have issues with instructions on docs, please open an issue: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/new/choose

Comment: Hi Dan now it's working, I am able to connect, you can close this issue. Also I have faced these kind of issues in docs where shared instructions in doc does not work after implementing them. I will raise all of them so it can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://localhost:9090 for graphana settings is what you need, I can reproduce the error you are seeing with the https endpoint as described in the tutorial. Here is it working:

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1040 fixes this