# Grafana Dashboard not populating the basic node metrics data

Tags: nodes, prometheus, metrics, telemetry

I am unable to populate substrate node metrics data in Grafana dashboard. I was following the instructions as shared in substrate doc [Visualise Node Metrics](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/node-metrics/)
I am able to establish the connection between Grafana and Prometheus after [this fix](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2738/error-reading-prometheus-post-https-localhost9090-api-v1-query-dial-tcp?noredirect=1#comment2597_2738) I am importing the basic [json template for metrics](https://docs.substrate.io/assets/tutorials/node-metrics/substrate-node-template-metrics.json) in grafana which is shared as part of the documentation above. I am reporting this issue to understand if everything provided in substrate doc is correct.[image]

Comment: too little detail, normally you may check it step by step. e.g: 1.query prometheus endpoint to see if data is ready, 2.check Grafana template config to see if metrics defined consistent with what in prometheus. 3... and so on.

Comment: The last time I checked the grafana dashboard config was outdated. It was updated two years ago. It that the one you are using?

Comment: @ron I know it's little detail, hard to detail being new to this. I have followed all the steps from doc. Also there are hardly any resource for new dev to refer on this topic. I have captured the screen presenting what all I am doing, I hope this helps you to understand my problem better. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BDyIivif1Bdp5AbVUW2yuM4WGVPHSQH8/view?usp=sharing) .

Comment: @oliver not sure how old is this stuff. I am using the Visualise Node Metrics doc for achieving this. But it does not work with said steps. I am not sure if all steps are complete there in doc and it's a challenge to troubleshoot as there is no other reference material to refer

Answer (score 1):

Use this one instead:

- https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13759

It works for me.

[image]

Here is the JSON for convenience:

```json
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": {
          "type": "datasource",
          "uid": "grafana"
        },
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "target": {
          "limit": 100,
          "matchAny": false,
          "tags": [],
          "type": "dashboard"
        },
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "Grafana dashboard for substrate template metrics. Instructions on use: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/visualize-node-metrics/",
  "editable": true,
  "fiscalYearStartMonth": 0,
  "gnetId": 13759,
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "id": 6,
  "links": [],
  "liveNow": false,
  "panels": [
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "What your node sees as the highest block (NOT finalized)",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "super-light-yellow",
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "id": 12,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "value",
        "graphMode": "none",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "last"
          ],
          "fields": "/^Height\\(best\\)$/",
          "values": false
        },
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "substrate_block_height{status=\"best\"}",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "Height(best)",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Block Height (best)",
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "What your node sees as the highest finalized block ( less than or equal to best)",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 3,
        "w": 6,
        "x": 6,
        "y": 0
      },
      "id": 13,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "value",
        "graphMode": "none",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "last"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "textMode": "value"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "substrate_block_height{status=\"finalized\"}",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "Height(finalized)",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Block Height (finalized)",
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "Total transactions in best block",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "yellow",
                "value": 100
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 3,
        "w": 6,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 3
      },
      "id": 16,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "value",
        "graphMode": "area",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "last"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "textMode": "auto"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "substrate_proposer_number_of_transactions",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "Height(best)",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Block Total Tx",
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "What your node sees as the highest finalized block ( less than or equal to best)",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "mappings": [],
          "thresholds": {
            "mode": "absolute",
            "steps": [
              {
                "color": "green",
                "value": null
              },
              {
                "color": "yellow",
                "value": 500000
              },
              {
                "color": "red",
                "value": 1000000
              }
            ]
          },
          "unit": "decbytes"
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 3,
        "w": 6,
        "x": 6,
        "y": 3
      },
      "id": 17,
      "options": {
        "colorMode": "value",
        "graphMode": "area",
        "justifyMode": "auto",
        "orientation": "auto",
        "reduceOptions": {
          "calcs": [
            "last"
          ],
          "fields": "",
          "values": false
        },
        "textMode": "value"
      },
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "substrate_state_cache_bytes",
          "format": "time_series",
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "Size (bytes)",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "title": "State Cashe (bytes)",
      "type": "stat"
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": true,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "Number of connected peers",
      "fieldConfig": {
        "defaults": {
          "links": []
        },
        "overrides": []
      },
      "fill": 1,
      "fillGradient": 0,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 8,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 6
      },
      "hiddenSeries": false,
      "id": 10,
      "legend": {
        "alignAsTable": true,
        "avg": true,
        "current": true,
        "max": true,
        "min": true,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": true
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "options": {
        "alertThreshold": true
      },
      "percentage": false,
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": true,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "substrate_sub_libp2p_peers_count",
          "instant": false,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "Number of network gossip peers",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeRegions": [],
      "title": "LibP2P peers",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 0,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "mode": "time",
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "$$hashKey": "object:673",
          "decimals": 0,
          "format": "none",
          "label": "Peers",
          "logBase": 1,
          "min": "0",
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "$$hashKey": "object:674",
          "format": "short",
          "logBase": 1,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false
      }
    },
    {
      "aliasColors": {},
      "bars": false,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "dashes": false,
      "datasource": {
        "type": "prometheus",
        "uid": "tSoTyKbnk"
      },
      "description": "histogram 90th quantiles for time to construct a block (seconds) More info: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile",
      "fill": 1,
      "fillGradient": 8,
      "gridPos": {
        "h": 8,
        "w": 12,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 14
      },
      "hiddenSeries": false,
      "id": 15,
      "legend": {
        "avg": false,
        "current": false,
        "max": false,
        "min": false,
        "show": true,
        "total": false,
        "values": false
      },
      "lines": true,
      "linewidth": 1,
      "nullPointMode": "null",
      "options": {
        "alertThreshold": true
      },
      "percentage": false,
      "pluginVersion": "8.5.3",
      "pointradius": 2,
      "points": false,
      "renderer": "flot",
      "seriesOverrides": [],
      "spaceLength": 10,
      "stack": false,
      "steppedLine": false,
      "targets": [
        {
          "expr": "histogram_quantile(0.90, sum(rate(substrate_proposer_block_constructed_bucket[5m])) by (le))",
          "format": "time_series",
          "instant": false,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "90th quantile for block construction time (s)",
          "refId": "A"
        }
      ],
      "thresholds": [],
      "timeRegions": [],
      "title": "Proposer Block Construction Time",
      "tooltip": {
        "shared": true,
        "sort": 0,
        "value_type": "individual"
      },
      "type": "graph",
      "xaxis": {
        "mode": "time",
        "show": true,
        "values": []
      },
      "yaxes": [
        {
          "$$hashKey": "object:517",
          "format": "short",
          "label": "Time (s)",
          "logBase": 1,
          "show": true
        },
        {
          "$$hashKey": "object:518",
          "format": "short",
          "logBase": 1,
          "show": true
        }
      ],
      "yaxis": {
        "align": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "refresh": "",
  "schemaVersion": 36,
  "style": "dark",
  "tags": [
    "substrate",
    "blockchain",
    "node",
    "template",
    "polkadot",
    "kusama"
  ],
  "templating": {
    "list": []
  },
  "time": {
    "from": "now-5m",
    "to": "now"
  },
  "timepicker": {
    "refresh_intervals": [
      "5s",
      "10s",
      "30s",
      "1m",
      "5m",
      "15m",
      "30m",
      "1h",
      "2h",
      "1d"
    ]
  },
  "timezone": "",
  "title": "Substrate Node Template Metrics",
  "uid": "PUYzGbwWa",
  "version": 4,
  "weekStart": ""
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks , I tried this json template it did work for me.